# Windows XP shortcut key for expanding folder in "Select Folder" dialog

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

Many programs have a "select folder" dialog, where the folders are displayed in tree form:

[image: It looks like this.]

What's the keyboard shortcut for *expanding* a folder in order to choose one of its subfolders? If I press Enter, the root folder itself will get chosen, and the dialog will close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right arrow key will usually expand in most trees.

Answer (score 1):

Right arrow key.

Comment: Setting a record here; Solved my own question less than a minute after asking :)

Comment: Well, Tofystedeth answered as fast as you did. As the original poster, you shouldn't answer your own question. I suggest deleting this answer and accepting the other answer.